# requests on app engine ('Connection aborted.', error(104, 'connection reset by peer'))

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, python-requests

I am getting the below error on google app engine. I am using requests module version 2.13, python 2.7 and django 1.10.4

My code works fine on local development server but raises connection error
in requests adapters.py. I not sure of the changes that need to be made while deploying for requests to work on app engine. can anyone help? Thank you!

/base/data/home/apps/s~comtimes/app8.399095082090835876/lib/requests/adapters.py 
raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)

```
conn <requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool.HTTPSConnectionPool object at 0xfa973450>
err ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', error(104, 'connection reset by peer'))
proxies  OrderedDict()
request  <PreparedRequest [GET]>
self     <requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter object at 0xfa973210>
stream   False
timeout  <requests.packages.urllib3.util.timeout.Timeout object at 0xfa9736d0>
```

Comment: just saw instructions on how to use requests on app engine (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/issue-requests#issuing_an_http_request).. will try it and update.

Comment: the above link has the answer